# extract a substring from a string in php

Tags: php

I have a string

```
$url = "http://www.example.com/index.php?1234567"
```

I only want the substring "http://www.example.com", that is extract the substring upto the third occurrence of the forward-slash character.

thanks in advance

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[php]+is%3Aanswer+parse_url

Comment: -1 [Please Do Your Homework before asking a question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask-advice). Even without know that there is `parse_url` this wouldn't have been hard to solve on your own with some prior research.

Comment: Gordon, as i'm new to php i really didn't know such function exists that why i posted here

Comment: Being new to PHP and not knowing such functions exist doesnt free you from searching. Please do so next time. Research is an essential skill for developers and the sooner you learn it, the better you'll be able to solve problems on your own.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
<?php
$url = 'http://www.example.com/index.php?1234567';

print_r(parse_url($url));

?>
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to look at [`parse_url()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php)

Answer (score 1):

```
$link = "http://www.something.cmo/sdfsdf";
$str  = explode("/", $link);

echo $str[2]; // is string without sub
```

Comment: If your code get corrected, it will print `www.something.cmo`, Otherwise PHP complains for errors.

Answer (score 1):

You should checkout: 
http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php

`parse_url()` will return you an associative array and you should lookup value for keys `host` and `scheme` to get what you need.

Kind regards,
Bo